# Algorithm to distinguish US TIN between SSN and EIN

Tags: php, regex

Tax payers in the Unites States must have a tax identification number of some kind.

It must either be a [Social Security Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number), or [Individual Taxpayer Identification Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individual_Taxpayer_Identification_Number) (for aliens, so that they can be taxed without being deported)

or a [Employer Identification Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employer_Identification_Number) for corporations

If you follow those links to wikipedia, it is simple to see that there is (or was in the case of social security numbers) a considerable amount of structure in these numbers. So much so that you can [often guess a social if you have region and birthdate](http://www.pnas.org/content/106/27/10975).  There is a php [library](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4575-PHP-Generate-and-validate-US-social-security-numbers.html) and [snippets](http://snipplr.com/view/14152/) to generate and validate SSNs that take advantage of these patterns.

Given a database full of both SSNs and EINs, is there a preexisting algorithm (and hopefully library) that can distinguish and validate between SSN EIN and ITIN? I would love a simple regex here, but that may be too hopeful.

There are companies that can do this with some reliability, but I have not found a public implementation, much less one with some data to show how reliable it is at the validation process.

Answer (score 4):

There was a [PHP library for SSNs](https://github.com/corbanworks/fng-ssn-tools/blob/master/fngssn.class.php), but the last time it was updated was 2013. It relies heavily on the [High Group List](https://www.ssa.gov/employer/ssnvhighgroup.htm), which is no longer used, now that [SSNs are randomized](https://www.ssa.gov/employer/randomization.html).

I am not aware of any libraries that handle SSNs, ITINs, and EINs. You may want to consult [this Django field for SSNs](http://django-localflavor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/localflavor/us/forms/#USSocialSecurityNumberField) for information on the complexity of validating just SSNs. Some of the complexities come from [SSN abuse](https://www.ssa.gov/history/ssn/misused.html) over the years, which have caused certain numbers to be invalid, making a regex very challenging, and a simple regex impossible.

[ITINs must start with 9](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/general-itin-information), but in 2013 the IRS changed which ranges are valid. Otherwise, they look just like SSNs.

There are only two differences between EINs and SSNs. First, EINs are grouped xx-xxxxxxx, and SSNs are xxx-xx-xxxx. The second is that there is a list of [valid prefixes for EINs](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/how-eins-are-assigned-and-valid-ein-prefixes), so if an EIN is presented that does not have a valid prefix, it can be determined to be invalid. EINs also used to be more geographic, but have been centralized, removing that geographic meaning. Ultimately, the only way you can distinguish between EINs and SSNs is if you require they be formatted with dashes, then validate the prefix.

Comment: bout time someone answered. Thank you!